# update the records in my database whose datagridview.selected row.check = true

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, datagrid

how can I bulk update my data in `datagridview.selectedrows`

I have harcoded code to fill datagridview2

```
 server_connection()
        adapt = New SqlDataAdapter
        dt = New DataTable
        com = New SqlCommand("SELECT AirbillNo As [Airbill], SubAirbill as [Sub], BRANCHES.BranchName as [Branch]  , DateOfAirbill as [Date], AIRBILLCLASS.ClassName, SERVICE.ServiceName,net + taxs as [Gross] , NET, TAXS, Addressee,Sender, SCOPE_TOWN.Towns as [Destination1],AIRBILLS.QTY as [QTY], Valuation, Insurance, PickupFee, OtherFee,  ExcessWeightAmount, Lenght, Width, Height,        Discounts, BillingTrid, StatementTRID FROM AIRBILLS INNER JOIN BRANCHES ON AIRBILLS.BranchID = BRANCHES.ID INNER JOIN AIRBILLCLASS ON AIRBILLCLASS.ID = AIRBILLS.ClassofAirbill INNER JOIN SCOPE_TOWN on SCOPE_TOWN.ID = AIRBILLS.TownDestinationID INNER JOIN SERVICE on SERVICE.ID = AIRBILLS.ServiceID WHERE ClientID = @Clid AND DateOfAirbill BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2 AND BillingTrid IS NULL", con)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Clid", CreateBilling.CID.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", CreateBilling.begindate.Value.Date)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", CreateBilling.enddate.Value.Date)
        adapt.SelectCommand = com
        adapt.Fill(dt)
        PreviewBilling.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        adapt.Update(dt)
        'day1 = Nothing
        'month1 = Nothing
        'year1 = Nothing
        PreviewBilling.DataGridView1.Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
        PreviewBilling.TextBox2.Text = Nothing
        PreviewBilling.ShowDialog()
```

this will be the result

https://ibb.co/duQmRT

I successfully update my database using this code

```
For Each airbills As DataGridViewRow In PreviewBilling.DataGridView1.Rows
       If airbills.Cells(0).Value = True Then
       server_connection()
       com = New SqlCommand("UPDATE AIRBILLS SET BillingTrid = @btrid where BranchID = @bid and  AirbillNo = @abno and TrackingNo = @tno", con)
                                com.Parameters.Add("@btrid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = billtrid
                                com.Parameters.Add("@bid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = branchID_CreateBilling
                                com.Parameters.Add("@abno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = airbills.Cells(1).Value
                                com.Parameters.Add("@tno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = branchID_CreateBilling & 2
                                com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                con.Close()

                            Else
                            End If
                        Next
```

but the problem is it loops in the entire datagridview to check if there is `selectedrows` in there, and if have it will update according to its data and it  keeps eating the users time

I want to update the records in my database whose selected `row.check = true` will be update bulk copy or fast..

Please help me, any suggestion will be much much appreciated

Comment: If you want to use the `SelectedRows` then use the `SelectedRows` rather than the `Rows`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: whahaha super fast I forgot the prperty selectedrows ahaha thanks jmcilhinney :D your always answering my question very well ahahah thanks again :D

Comment: @jmcilhinney   oops... its not updating... coz the one that my codes are identify is the row(0) which is the checkbox in the column 0 if i check the checkbox i want only the check one to be updated

Comment: So this doesn't really have anything to do with selection and rather has to do with checking a specific column? In that case, you can simply filter based on that: `PreviewBilling.DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Where(Function(row) CBool(row.Cells(0).Value))`.  You may have to adjust that slightly if there might be NULLs in the column but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i think your PreviewBilling.DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Where(Function(row) CBool(row.Cells(0).Value)) and If airbills.Cells(0).Value = True Then else if is the same coz the speed  if there has an option but if not i leave it as it is :D